# Why contract functions returning different values for similar input?

Tags: solidity, remix

In remix-ide below contract output is 25 from function `Test1` and 20 from function `Test2`
for calculation `(5/2)*10` .

I want to understand why two function returning different values for similar input? x = 5 and y=2

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: AGPL-3.0-or-later

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Test{

    function Test1() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return (5 / 2) * 10;
    }

    function Test2(uint256 x, uint256 y) public pure returns (uint256) {
        return (x / y) * 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you **sure** that you are inputting the correct integer values? May sound like a stupid question - but is an easy mistake (e.g 2/1*10 or 10/5*10 etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason for this is that `function Test1()` is actually doing no calculation once it's called.

The value written inside of `Test1()` => `(5/2)*10` is actually a `constant` that is calculated and written into the contract code **during the compile time**.

Example:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENCED

pragma solidity 0.8.3;  


contract Test{

    function Test0() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return 25;
    }

    function Test1() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return (5 / 2) * 10;
    }

    function Test2(uint256 x, uint256 y) public pure returns (uint256) {
        return (x / y) * 10;
    }


}
```

Executing `Test0` && `Test1` will both "cost" around **21400 gas** while Test2 will "cost" around **22400 gas**. The reason for this is that `Test0 && Test1` are just returning the constant variable values, while `Test2` is actually doing the calculation.

NOTE: (None of these functions will spend gas, as they are not writing anything into the blockchain, but the gas values help show the difference in the complexity of the function)

Comment: This is the right answer. The solidity docs explain that numbers keep arbitrary precision during compile-time computations, while of course during run-time there are only integers: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#rational-and-integer-literals

Answer (score 0):

Solidity does not accept decimal values.
If you notice.. You can try returning only 5/2 and not *10. It will throw an error saying type conversion not possible.

In Test1, the values are hard coded. So the compiler knows what it has to do when it gets a decimal point (that doesn't go away- throws an error,, and when it does go away, it accepts what is happening)

In Test2, we pass 2 parameters. The compiler doesn't know whether the result of operation (be it any, addition, subtraction, etc) will be a true integer or a floating point value. So, in order to deal with the problems. It always considers the floor value (i.e rounding to lower digit. Even if value is 2.9 it will show 2)

That is why, you get 25 in Test1 and 20 in Test2